# How to change name in json for show in page

Tags: javascript, html, json, typescript, ionic2

I want to change name in json for show in page (ion-select)

mycodehtml

```
ion-select [(ngModel)]="refine" (ionChange)="optionsFn(item, i);" >
        <ion-option [value]="item"  *ngFor="let item of totalfilter;let i = index" >{{item["@NAME"]}}</ion-option>
      </ion-select>
```

myjson

```
"FACETLIST":{
    "FACET":[
      {
        "@NAME":"creator",
        "@COUNT":"2"

      },
      {
        "@NAME":"lang",
        "@COUNT":"1"
      },
      {
        "@NAME":"rtype",
        "@COUNT":"1"
      }

    ],
    "FACET":[

      {
        "@NAME":"lang",
        "@COUNT":"4"
      },
      {
        "@NAME":"rtype",
        "@COUNT":"2"
      }

]

}
```

this above ionic select show creator lang and rtype but I want to change @NAME for show in page

> example creator->Creator, lang->Language

But I do not want to change value in json (I want to change for show in page)

Comment: Why don't you make a copy of this JSON with desired values and utilize that one in view. Or dirty soln could be that put if check in loop and convert these two in desired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I think for your *ngFor you can use PipeTransform:

Create a pipe file: mypipe.ts

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'mypipe', pure: false
})
export class MyPipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(items: any[]): any[] {

        return items.filter(it => it["@NAME"] = it["@NAME"].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + it["@NAME"].slice(1));
    }

}
```

Add a import for your pipe:

```
import {MyPipe} from "./mypipe";
```

Add at declarations (@NgModule):

```
@NgModule({

  imports: [ YourModule]
  declarations: [ YourApp, MyPipe ],
  bootstrap: [ YourApp ]
})
```

And finally, change your *ngFor:

```
<ion-select [(ngModel)]="refine" (ionChange)="optionsFn(item, i);" >
        <ion-option [value]="item"  *ngFor="let item of totalfilter | mypipe;let i = index" >{{item["@NAME"]}}</ion-option>
      </ion-select>
```

Complete solution for Angular2, but not for ionic2, I put on plunker:

https://plnkr.co/edit/nIYRcmHPZkhoH6PyK8o4?p=preview

Comment: Ok, I changed for your exactly solution, change your pipe using this edit, or copy the complete solution

Comment: Hey @fongfuse any problem? Let me now if you want some additional help

Comment: If `lang` ->`Language` , Thank you for your help. T-T

Comment: Hey @fongfuse it easy to fix this doing a string replace in pipe, so can you accept my solution?

Comment: If I want `ion-select` to show `lang` and `rtype` only ,How to set it? **I edited my json ,please read the above.

Comment: hey , I'm try on ionic2 is not working and error is still " Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined"  sorry again.